# promblem in passng dynamic array through session

Tags: php

i am workng on dynamic arrray when i passed these array from one page to next it display me the empty array.my dynamic array on page2.php contain the result of some computation .

coding of fetchng data in the form of array from database

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {$a[]=$row['c1'];
    $b[]=$row['c2'];
    $c[]=$row['c3'];
    $d[]=$row['c4'];
    $m[]=round(($row['c1']/$row['c4']),2);
    $n[]=round(($row['c2']/$row['c4']),2);
    $o[]=round(($row['c3']/$row['c4']),2);
    $row_count++;

    }
```

here below i pass the array in session

```
<?php
require_once('nf.php');
$_SESSION['name'] =$r;
$_SESSION['name1'] = $r1;
$_SESSION['name2'] = $r2;
for($i=0;$i<$row_count;$i++)
echo "Efficiency ".($i+1);
  echo "<tr>";

     $f=implode($m,',');
     $r=explode(',',$f);
     print_r($r);

     $f1=implode($n,',');
     $r1=explode(',',$f1);
      print_r($r1);

     $f2=implode($o,',');
     $r2=explode(',',$f2);
      print_r($r2);
}
```

on page3.php
i am gettng array like ths

```
<?php
require_once('nf.php');
$r= $_SESSION['name'];
echo $r;
var_dump($r);
print_r($r);
$r1= $_SESSION['name1'];
echo $r1;
print_r($r1);

$r2= $_SESSION['name2'];
echo $r2;
print_r($r2);

?>
```

nf.php contain `session_start();`

when i display these array on page3.php i get the `array empty` on button click
plz help me

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions don't save the arrays you're defining inside the while while you're fetching data.

You have to do an explicit assignment.

```
$_SESSION['m'] = ...;
```

instead of

```
$m[] = ...;
```

and so on.

Comment: does i change something else in it also

Comment: sir when i usng ths in the way u asked i cant get the array values in $f=implode($m,','); sir tell me the way

Comment: You should study about PHP arrays before doing anything. The last message told me you know almost nothing about PHP.